# Can aesthetic experience being induced?

Tags: phenomenology, art

Can aesthetic experiences being induced ? Or are those bound to specific aspects of an objects or quality?

This small excerpt from a text on Ponty and minimalism in art says:

“from Merleau-Ponty’s claim: “It is, therefore, quite true that any perception of a thing, a shape or a size as real, any perceptual constancy refers back to the positioning of a world and of a system of experience in which my body is inescapably linked with phenomena… it is my involvement in a point of view which makes possible both the finiteness of my perception and its opening out upon the complete world as a horizon of every perception.””

“This idea is visually manifested within the Minimalist aesthetic, which espouses an art object that is reflexive and that heightens one’s awareness of oneself within the work, as it demands interaction between the object itself, its container, and the person moving within it”

[here](https://artsugar.co/blogs/news/phenomenology)the full text

Now I start having a lot of doubts that an art work could “heightens one’s awareness of oneself within the work”. Aesthetic experience occurs, and cannot be caused, beyond the conceptual fascination with artist’s intention to perceive the object directly without any filter or representation, could embodied experience being caused?
I remember a text about atmospheres from Griffero, in which he was extremely caution about the notion of “creating” an atmosphere Vs the notion of creating the condition for an atmosphere to emerge…

Answer (score 0):

> Can aesthetic experiences being induced? Or are those bound to specific aspects of an objects or quality.

I don't understand these two sentences as they are not grammatically or aesthetically well-formed. Ironic when you're talking about aesthetics ...

> Now I start having a lot of doubts that an artwork could "heightens one's awareness of oneself within the work.

Sure, it can be. Have you never 'lost' yourself in a film, theatre or book?

Traditional art is reflective between man and man or man and divinity. This is why Judd, an art critic, argued that minimalism was perverse in it's philosophy by denying any such engagement. This is reflected in other names for this movement: neo-dadaism and nihilism. It's also reflected in the title of an essay name-checked right at the beginning of your linked article: *The Double Negative: A New Syntax for Sculpture* by Robert Morris and Rosalind Krauss. Syntax is about form and not semantics, it is what remains when semantics - ie human reflectivity - is taken out.

The author quotes Krauss as stating:

> Heizer's image therefore depicts the intervention of the outside world into the body's internal being, taking up residence there and forming it's motivations and meanings.

This is almost Kant's 'Copernican Turn' to the object rather than the mind, except Kant did not make the error of no mind at all. And I doubt Merleau-Ponty did as well as phenomenology derives from Kants turn.